# Why is √(1 - (|(|x|-2)|-1)^2 ) not integrable?

Tags: integration

Stuck with this question of √(1 - 〖(|(|x|-2)|-1)〗^2 )
Don't know why it is not integrable? Can somebody help please?!

Comment: Goodness, this needs MathJax.  Badly.  I'll see what I can do, but OP needs to confirm.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(|x|-2)^2}}$?

Comment: Presumably related to [past question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2118916/120540). Do you know it's not integrable, or are you just assuming this based on the fact that nobody answered yesterday's question?